# How to refactor this code with two same class name and same helper methods with different return types?

Tags: c#, oop, refactoring

I have two classes like below:

```
public async A GernerateStuff(int expireDays = 15)
{
    using var randomNumberGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    var randomBytes = new byte[64];
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomBytes);
    return new A
    {
        Stuff = Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes),
        Created = now,
        Expires = now.AddDays(expireDays)
    };
}

public async B GernerateStuff(int expireDays = 10)
{
    using var randomNumberGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    var randomBytes = new byte[64];
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomBytes);

    return new B
    {
        Stuff = Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes),
        Created = now,
        Expires = now.AddDays(expireDays)
    };
}

public class A
{
    public string Stuff{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Stuff{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}
```

The constraint is: I can not create just one class instead of two separate classes A and B as they have significant differences in usage.

Now, my question is: how can I clean this code up having both classes A and B but a single method for `GernerateStuff`?

I can create an interface like this:

```
public class A : IInterface
{
}

public class B : IInterface
{

}

public interface IInterface
{
    public string Stuff{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the problem is how `public async IInterface GernerateStuff(int expireDays = 15)` signature would handle both class A and B?

Comment: I was trying to do that but for public async IInterface GernerateStuff(int expireDays = 15) signature how would I return an interface type that would handle both class A and B?

Comment: Use only one, they are exactly the same. Don't overengineering.

Comment: Thinking about it, your method could be moved to a static class, since it doesnt seem to depend on any instance level info of either A or B. You could then make it a generic method i.e. T GenerateStuff<T>(int expireDays)

Comment: Yes, I agree with @PabloCaballero. Don't over engineer it.

Comment: I disagree with Pablo Caballero and Francis Decena. Separating types is _not_ overengineering. There might be very good reasons for that e.g. changes in the future that are to be expected.

Comment: Thanks for understanding @MarkusSafar! There is very valid reason in this case as I can't share the whole private codebase here to validate the reasoning. I appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways tot achieve this. One has already been mentioned in other answeres, which is about using generics. However this assumes your types `A` and `B` do even have anything in common that you could use as common generic constraint - e.g a common base-interface. Then you could do this:

```
public async T GernerateStuff<T>(int expireDays = 15) where T: new(), MyInterface
{
    using var randomNumberGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    var randomBytes = new byte[64];
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomBytes);
    return new T
    {
        Stuff = Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes),
        Created = now,
        Expires = now.AddDays(expireDays)
    };
}
```

You could also create a factory that creates the instances of `A` or `B` depending on some condition - e.g. some configuration. However you'd also need a common base-interface for that:

```
public async MyInterface GernerateStuff(int expireDays = 15)
{
    using var randomNumberGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    var randomBytes = new byte[64];
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomBytes);
    return CreateTheThing(Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes), now, now.AddDays(expireDays));
}

MyInterface CreateTheThing(string stuff, DateTime created, DateTime expires)
{
    if(...)
        return new A { ... }
    else if(...)
        return new B { ... }
    return new C { ... }
}
```

This solution has the advantage, that you don't need to change the client-logic when you add a new type to the factory. All you need to change is the factory itself by introducing `new C { ... }`. Furthermor a client cannot provide any types that actually don't work, as they don't provide any type-information at all.

By the way your method does not `await` anything, so there's no reason to make it `async`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a static factory method and inject it as a parameter:

```
public static A CreateA(byte[] stuff, DateTime now, DateTime expires)
    => new A{  Stuff = stuff,   Created = now,  Expires = expires  }

...
public static T GernerateStuff<T>(Func<byte[], DateTime, DateTime, T> ctor, int expireDays = 15)
{
    using var randomNumberGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    var randomBytes = new byte[64];
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomBytes);
    return ctor(    
        Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes),
        now,
        now.AddDays(expireDays)
    ;
}
...
var a = GernerateStuff(CreateA);
```

But if class A and B are identical, why not use the same class? This is a definite code smell, and you should probably think about how you model your problem some more.  Also, `async` does not serve any point without an await, so get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am little bit late at the party, however you can use dictionary with delegates which can provide lazy initialization.

Let me show an example. At first, we need to make enums to avoid `if else` statements while creating instances of classes:

```
public enum FooType
{
    A, B
}
```

Then we need to have abstract base class which has the same behaviour for all derived classes:

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
    public string? Stuff { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}
```

And derived classes look like this:

```
public class A : FooBase
{
    public A(int expireDays)
    {
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"I am A class";
    
}

public class B : FooBase
{
    public B(int expireDays)
    {
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"I am B class";
}
```

Then Factory looks like this and you can customize any property or method if you want to:

```
public class FooFactory
{
    Dictionary<FooType, Func<FooBase>> _fooBaseByType;

    public Func<FooBase> GetInstance(FooType fooType, int expireDays) 
    {
        _fooBaseByType = new Dictionary<FooType, Func<FooBase>>
        {
            { 
                FooType.A, () => new A(expireDays) 
                { 
                    Created = SomeCustomDateTime(), 
                    Stuff = SomeCustomString()
                } 
            },
            {   
                FooType.B, () => new B(expireDays) 
                { 
                    Created = SomeCustomDateTime()
                } 
            }
        };

        return _fooBaseByType[fooType];
    }

    private DateTime SomeCustomDateTime() => DateTime.Now;
    private string SomeCustomString() => "My custom string";
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
FooFactory factory = new FooFactory();
A a = (A)factory.GetInstance(FooType.A, 11)();
```